# Calculating heat of combustion via calorimetry

Tags: thermodynamics

**Question:**

> When $\pu{60 g}$ of $\ce{C60}$ is combusted in a bomb calorimeter that has a water jacket containing $\pu{300.0 g}$ of water, the temperature of the water increases by $\pu{10 ^\circ C}$. Assuming that the specific heat of water is $\pu{4.18 J g^{-1} K^{-1}}$, estimate $\Delta E$ of combustion per mole of $\ce{C60}$.

**Answer**: $\pu{-150.5 kJ/mol}$

**What I have tried:**
$$
\begin{align}
Q &= m \times c \times \Delta T \\
Q &= 300 \times 4.18 \times 10
\end{align}$$

That's the only equation I know and it doesn't seem to work for this problem.

Comment: 1) *chemistry help question* and *more chemistry help?* are not titles that would be in any way likely to help future visitors of the site. You have a rather specific problem in both your questions, you should have titled them appropriately. 2) I don’t believe that that be the only equation you know.

Comment: @Jan Ok, I changed the title and obliviously I know more equations but in this regard I don't. I don't know any other equation that could be applied to solve this problem, so for the sake of other future visitors to this site can you at least point me in the right direction because i'm completely lost

Comment: Suggestion 1: Add units. (That should be a given for all equations.) Then you should realise what you have just calculated, what that is equivalent to physically and maybe then you can see which step is remaining.

Comment: @Jan That calculates the energy needed to raise the temperate, I know the change in energy is would be E final - E initial so if I did that formula for both masses it would give me 12,540 for water and 2508 for Carbon, but subtracting them wouldn't give me 150.4 kj/mol which is the answer?

Comment: How did you just arrive at $12540$, what is its unit and how did carbon get in there?

Comment: What I assumed is Q must be the energies so I applied that equation for both water which would be (300 grams of water) * (4.18) * (10) which would give me 12540. I did the same for Carbon, I assume it's carbon because it has a "C" for it's symbol, and when I did the same for carbon it gave me 2508. So when I got the two energies I subtracted them but it wasn't even close to 150.5 jk/mol.

Comment: One last time: *Please* use units, it gets you so much further.

Comment: I see what you mean but now I'm even more confused now, you were initially confused on why I had factored in Carbon into this, so am I not suppose to use carbon? Because I wouldn't know how else to find moles of carbon. but even assuming that was true 12540 joules/ 5 moles of carbon wouldn't be 150.5 kj/mol?

Comment: Ah, we’re almost there. Why are you using $5~\mathrm{mol}$ of carbon, because in the question there clearly are *not* $5~\mathrm{mol}$ of carbon. Check out which type of carbon you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 60 g of $\ce{C60}$ (which has a molecular weight of 720.6), so that means you'll need to multiply your answer by 720.6/60 which (cleverly) turns out to be 12.01. Another way of saying it is that you have calculated the heat of combustion for 1/12.01 moles of $\ce{C60}$, so you'll need to multiply your answer by the inverse in order to get the desired (per mole) quantity.

Using your notation, numbers, and noting that a change in one degree Celsius is equivalent to a change in one kelvin:

$$\Delta E_{\rm molar} = -12.01\;\mathrm{mol} \cdot 300\;{\mathrm g} \cdot 4.18\;{\mathrm J} \cdot {\mathrm g}^{-1}\, \cdot {\mathrm K}^{-1}\, \cdot 10\;{\mathrm K} = -150.6054\;\mathrm{kJ}\cdot\mathrm{mol}^{-1}$$

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've been trying to figure this out for hours